# Showing progress in whiptail while using sshpass and SCP

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm writing a bash script that automates the building, copying and running of a golang app to a remote server. I'm using `whiptail` to let the user pick some options, enter in some details (e.g. SSH server name, username and password).

When I use `sshpass -p mypassword scp myfile user@remoteserver:/location/to/myfile` I don't get any progress, the terminal just sits there until it's copied, then carries on. Obviously I can't pass this to whiptail's gauge option. When I run it without sshpass, I get progress info on the screen, but I'd rather use sshpass (not to mention when scp asks for a password, it breaks whiptail's dialog box). Running scp with -v gives tons of debug info but nothing I can clean up and feed into whiptail

So how would I go about showing a progress bar to the user while the file is copied over SSH?

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with sshpass. scp however, has a progress bar using the -3 option.

```
 $ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     50043369 Jul 17 21:59 gv.tgz

j0h@M0h:~$ scp -3 -P 7935 gv.tgz  j0h@123.1.2.3:/home/j0h/
j0h@123.1.2.3's password: 
gv.tgz                       100%   48MB  11.9MB/s   00:04
```

Durring the upload, the last line was changing, indicating progress from 0% to 100%. is this something you can use?